# What is the per day limit for Review Suggested Edits?

Tags: discussion, review, suggested-edits

I am often reviewing suggested edit questions and mostly I am allowed 20 reviews, but sometimes I am allowed 40 reviews, so I want to know: What is the rule for limit per day?

Actually, I have no any issue regarding this, but I am just asking for my curiosity's sake.